# Angular expression inside an ng-repeat not being rendered when parent scope referenced

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, expression, directive

so I'm working on an elastic search implementation in Angular. So far so good but I'm running into a weird situation. Each result has an associated tag(s) that can be user-generated.

Here is my form & input:

```
<form ng-submit="search($event)" class="queryBuilder ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchQuery" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
</form>
```

The results are displaying just fine and so are the tags. The problem comes into play when I click on the tags. Initially, the issue was while inside the repeat, they didn't have access to the above `searchQuery` model so I simply changed it to target `$parent.searchQuery` and that worked but dig this, as soon as I did that the expression `item.tag` no longer worked. Now it's outputting the actual curly brackets and all.

```
<button ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="$parent.searchQuery = $parent.searchQuery + ' {{item.tag}}'; search();" class="tag ng-binding ng-scope">Tag Name</button>
```

I'm very new to Angular, been using jQuery for a billion years so I apologize in advance if I'm missed something very basic. I've searched around and can find scope related material but not expressions inside an `ng-repeat` clashing with targeting parent scope. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals (`searchQuery` here in this case) and primitives can not be referenced over the nested scopes in Angular or Javascript. Read a famous tutorial on this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

You used `$parent` which was working initially but when you attached `ng-repeat` it starts breaking because `ng-repeat` creates a new scope so now your `$parent` property is referencing to a different scope.

Regarding how you fix it: define an object in your controller like:

```
$scope.globalData = {};
```

Now reference your every `ng-model` with this object so to avoid the scope problems:

```
<form ng-submit="search($event)" class="queryBuilder ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <input type="text" ng-model="globalData.searchQuery" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
</form>
```

And your `ng-repeat` to like this:

```
<button ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="globalData.searchQuery = globalData.searchQuery + ' {{item.tag}}'; search();" class="tag ng-binding ng-scope">Tag Name</button>
```

This will reference your search query model with a Javascript `Object` and `Object` in Javascript can be referenced by the child instances or in case of Angular, can be referenced in the nested `$scope`.

Just make sure you put define that `gloabalData` (or whatever name you like) in a top level controller like one added to `<html>` or `<body`> tag so that it's scope can be available throughout the app. And of course, you don't have to use the `$parent` now :-)

Also, you can clean up your `ng-click` expression like:

```
ng-click="globalData.searchQuery = globalData.searchQuery + ' ' + item.tag; search();"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method on your controller:

```
$scope.clickItem = function(item){
    $scope.searchQuery += ' ' + item.category;
    $scope.search();
};
```

View:

```
<button ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="clickItem(item)" class="tag">foundation</button>
```